# How much does the dot operator affect efficiency?

Tags: c++, performance

How much does using the dot operator to access some data cost speed-wise? Eg:

```
struct A{
    public:
       A(): a(0){};
       int a;
};

int main(){
       A obj;
       int b = 0;

       cout << obj.a;  // How much slower is this
       cout << b;      // Than this...?

       return 0;
}
```

I know I should benchmark, but are there any general understandings here?

Comment: *Huh?!* Uhm.. you know... there isn't any difference in that code.

Comment: `struct A{  int a = 0; };` is ill formed!

Comment: There's got to be some inefficiency in using the data access operator...? Hasn't there?!

Comment: For starters, you code won't compile. Initializing directly in a struct (or class) is not valid. Other than that it's no different, the compiler just fetches from a different offset on the stack in this case.

Comment: "I know I should benchmark". Well you should.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's valid C++11.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Damn you C++11! Why did you have to change so much! Ah well, you learn something new every day I guess. :)

Comment: @user965369: why? c++ isnt like qbasic where every additional character slows the program down. There are libraries like boost.units that have thousands of lines, but exactly zero runtime impact.

Comment: Already looking at the generated assembly would help, probably even more than benchmarking.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I've got a pretty tight stream decoding algorithm and I'm just trying to push out as many speed affecting factors as possible

Comment: @user965369: By that logic you need to make your variable and type names shorter too..

Comment: Most Vexing Parse in the new version.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I think you missunderstood my question. I wondered by how much using the dot operator would affect speed. Modulus operator it is generally quite slow because of all the bitwise crap it has to do, so how 'slow' is the data access operator? Nothing to do with code readabillity

Comment: @user965369: `a` or `obj.a` are just two different symbolic names for a place in memory. There is no `operator.` function that is being called to access the memory. A relevant difference is how much the compiler knows about the places at run- and at compiletime. In this case it knows the same things about both at compile time.

Comment: This question shows a lack of understanding of the language. I suggest that you first learn the language and the idioms, assuming that it will be efficient. Only if you have a program that seems to be slow, consider learning to profile and analyze the results and focus on understanding where the cost is. But in the meantime, ignore performance.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's what I mean! What determines whether the compiler knows about the places and if it doesn't, how much slower will it be?

Comment: @user965369: the implementation of the compiler, and of course the general availability of the information. when its not there, the compiler cant do anything about it. but it can chose to ignore information that is there.

Comment: @PlasmaHH are there any general rules that determine what it ignores?

Comment: @user965369: no, the compiler writers are free to do whatever they want, as long as the observable behaviour of the code stays within the boundaries specified by the standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's take a look at dissasembled code:

```
       cout << obj.a;  // How much slower is this
0041161D  mov         esi,esp 
0041161F  mov         eax,dword ptr [obj] 
00411622  push        eax  
00411623  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (41A34Ch)] 
00411629  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (41A35Ch)] 
0041162F  cmp         esi,esp 
00411631  call        @ILT+430(__RTC_CheckEsp) (4111B3h) 
       cout << b;      // Than this...?
00411636  mov         esi,esp 
00411638  mov         eax,dword ptr [b] 
0041163B  push        eax  
0041163C  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (41A34Ch)] 
00411642  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (41A35Ch)] 
00411648  cmp         esi,esp 
0041164A  call        @ILT+430(__RTC_CheckEsp) (4111B3h)
```

This was compiled without optimizations. And even so, they take the same time.
With optimizations, the code is shorter, but still remains largely the same:

```
       cout << obj.a;  // How much slower is this
00401000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (40203Ch)] 
00401006  push        0    
00401008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (402038h)] 
       cout << b;      // Than this...?
0040100E  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (40203Ch)] 
00401014  push        0    
00401016  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (402038h)]
```

So for your snippet, the performance is identical. Small differences might occur on different compilers, but the overhead will always be negligible or 0.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, probably none as your `struct A a` and `int b` should both be optimized away into constants.

More in general, `.` means an offset has to be computed, but often (part of) that computation may be done at compile-time. This is not something you should be worried about. Also, if you have, say, multiple variables instead of a single `struct` on the stack, then accessing them might require exactly the same offset computations.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, none. At all.

This can heavily depend on your circumstances- if `obj` is a reference to memory which is not currently in cache, for example, large node-based structures, then it can cost you. Else, it's almost zero. The compiler will ensure that in many or even most cases, it is literally zero.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it doesn't make any difference, because `obj.a` can be resolved at compile-time and will not produce any overhead at runtime. You might be interested in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.115.578&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=-jTGTrqQMsap4gSQu_Q9&usg=AFQjCNEaBaoWLAQChp8EWsPF4S_eixKzIw&cad=rja)(pdf) which analyzes the cost of dispatching virtual function calls.

Answer (score 2):

The only *possible* run-time overhead when using the member-access-operator is when dealing with references to base classes and calling a virtual function. But that's really the *only* possibility. Accessing members will never have a run-time overhead through this operator.

Answer (score 1):

Both `obj.a`, `(&obj)->a` and `*(int*)(&obj+0)` are same. The `offset` Here `0` is added to the beginning address. To access it. and I as its not virtual its calculation at compile time. so no extra runtime cost associated with it.